# How do I put a string in a variable

Tags: string, assembly, x86-16, masm

I'm doing an program in assembly 8086 processor, but i have one doubt. I want move one word to my created string, but the assembler shows me an error: `error A2004: constant value too large`.

Declaration:

`Fich  db  'menu.txt',0`

doing this:

`mov Fich,'menu.txt'`

Comment: Please provide processor you're targeting, as well as assembler you're using.

Comment: Why do you want to write a program in assembly? It seems that you don not really realise what is it about…

Comment: @kirelagin That's precisely why he's asking a question ;)

Comment: I think, you will find answer here: http://www.winasm.net/forum/index.php?showtopic=3134

Comment: @phant0m Well, yeah, we all ask question just because we don't realise something =). But before starting to write a program in a language one should get to know its purpose and limitations.

Comment: @kirelagin - What's wrong with wanting to learn about writing assembly code?

Comment: There are no "variables" in assembly languages. Also, it is not possible to have two explicit memory operands for an instruction in x86.

Comment: @STLDeveloper Nothing wrong, it's very laudable. But before starting to write assembly one shoul know what is a register, what is memory, and what you can do with them.

Answer (score 2):

In 8086 assembler, you cannot move a string of bytes into a memory location using a `mov` statement.

You can move strings using the `movsb` statement by loading the source address in the `SI` register, the destination address in the `DI` register, and the length of the string in the `CX` register, and then finally calling `MOVSB`.

Here is a simple example:

```
TARGET db 80 dup(0)
SOURCE db 'Hello', 0

mov si, offset SOURCE  ; address of SOURCE
mov di, offset TARGET  ; address of TARGET
mov cx, 6              ; number of bytes to move (size of SOURCE)
rep movsb              ; move cx number of bytes from SOURCE to TARGET
```

Comment: Thanks @STLDeveloper, but i dont know how i do this. I'm starting in this language. Can you help me?

Comment: @Marco Barbosa I think you should get a book on that. Assembler is not something you learn by randomly googling things.

Comment: @DavidJashi Well, it's definitely possible to learn asm by googling things. The amount of randomness is what matters.

Comment: @kirelagin Well, if he googles a nice book to read on that matter - surely.

Comment: @MarcoBarbosa - I've added a simple example for you.  Good luck - your persistence will pay off.

Comment: Good example... but I think you want `rep movsb`.

Comment: @FrankKotler - great catch!  I appreciate you catching that!  I've corrected the example.